# Securing a Web Service for use in Mobile Devices

Tags: wcf, web-services, security

I have a web service that I would like to use from a few different mobile applications.  The data is not at the user level, but I don't want just anyone to be able to access the data.  I want to limit the data access to just the mobile applications, but I don't know what I can do to prevent someone else from possibly writing an application that uses the same data.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: is a question how can differentiate mobile device users from the general internet users? or How can prevent people using my data deployed in my web server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Javascripts/browser detection to "Guess" the device type and make a decision based on that. However this will not be an accurate detection and may have some cases of false detections, which can only be resolved by knowing more about the application and how the users are accessing it.

I must point out that it will be very hard if not impossible to keep out a determined user who can evade this kind of checks and still use data.